# How to match a tail end with the right type?

Tags: list, scala

I'm using the `case first::rest` pattern to recursively break apart lists. But apparently, this makes `rest` a `List[Any]`, even if the original List was of a specific type.

I tried changing it to `case first::(rest:List[Char])`, but that just gave a more confusing, unrelated error. I'd rather not have to cast if I can avoid it.

---

Here's the full code (I'm using SimplyScala.com). Yes, I'm trying to be tricky, as a way of exploring the language.

```
def paren(chars: List[Char], ct:Int = 0): Boolean = {
    case Nil => ct==0
    case c::tl => {
        paren(tl, ct + (c match { //!ERROR! tl is a List[Any] instead of List[Char]
            case '(' => 1
            case ')' => -1
            case _ => 0
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use `def paren(chars: List[Char], ct:Int = 0): Boolean = chars match {`? Without that, you're defining a anonymous partial function but not specifying the type of the parameters - the compiler can't tell that `c::tl` is supposed to match `chars` - so there is no "original list ... of a specified type"

Comment: The missing `chars match` is a syntactic error and the real issue.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, sorry. Are you saying you meant to add the `chars match`? Or are you saying they shouldn't be needed? Without them, your def is returning a (partial) function, but the signature you have says Boolean. Hence the errors you get. What are you trying to achieve? It's not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be better suited to using guards on your matches instead of your nested matches:

```
def paren(chars: List[Char], ct: Int = 0): Boolean = chars match {
  case Nil => ct == 0
  case h :: t if h == '(' => paren(t, ct + 1)
  case h :: t if h == ')' => paren(t, ct - 1)
  case h :: t => paren(t, ct)
}
```

And by adding the `chars match {...}`, the statement will compile just fine.

If you'd like to do without the `chars match {...}` part, then you'll need to use it as a `PartialFunction` which will involve switching the order of your parameters, i.e.:

```
def paren(ct: Int = 0): List[Char] => Boolean = {
  case Nil => ct == 0
  case h :: t if h == '(' => paren(ct + 1)(t)
  case h :: t if h == ')' => paren(ct - 1)(t)
  case h :: t => paren(ct)(t)
}
```

And if don't mind using [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz), then you can just use the `Foldable` and `IntMonoid` type classes that they already provide to make things even easier for you.  You just need to provide a simple Functor to convert `Char => Int` like so:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val paren: List[Char] => Boolean = _.foldMap({(_: Char) match {
  case '(' => 1
  case ')' => -1
  case _ => 0
}}) === 0
```

Comment: That's exactly what I had before, mod var names.

Comment: Which version of Scala are you using that was giving you the error?

Comment: SimplyScala.com. Is it possible that I'm just not allowed to do `:type = {...}`, and have to use `:type = chars match {...}`? That'd be embarrassing.

Comment: Yes. I upvoted your answer because I noticed the syntax error from it. Not sure what to do with this question now.

Comment: I edited my answer to show how you could avoid the `:type = chars match {...}` declaration by using `PartialFunction`s or how to avoid encoding the traversal logic entirely by using Scalaz's typeclasses.  You could then modify my Scalaz answer to work across any many different collection classes instead of just List.

Comment: "better suited to using guards on your matches instead of your nested matches [...] Then the type inferencer will work just fine." - it's not the guards that make it work, though. Just adding `chars match ` is enough  to get the type inference to work

Comment: Good point, Paul.  I've removed that statement as it's not correct.